# Use Gmail for incoming mail, and own mail server for outgoing email

Tags: email-server, gmail

I want to switch to Gmail from Google apps to handle my email. I have some internal programs that send emails to me like cronjobs, logwatch, and php applications.

Is there a way to sill have the internal programs send email. The emails will be sent to account from gmail.

I will close all incoming email ports on my system, and only have the outgoing ports open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar question here the other day and solved it using [this](http://sudhanshuraheja.com/2009/02/slicehost-setup-outgoing-mail-google-apps-postfix/). It looks simple and it is and it works, I can send email from my VPS only and receive mail at my Google apps address. just make you setup you [MX](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33352) records (setting an [SPF](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hlrm=en&answer=33786) record is also a good idea to help with anti spam measures), set a hostname in postfix ([main.cf](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html)) , make the changes suggested in the link and your good to go.  You dont need any firewall rules because you dont need an open port to send mail (at least i dont seem to need anyway) (I think and wait to be corrected by someone more knowledgeable if wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Either direct the apps to send mail to the Gmail account, or set up an alias in your local MTA that points to the Gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Its a fairly common setup for linux distros to configure sendmail by default to only listen to the loopback interface.  Then its just a matter of either configuring your apps to email the gmail address, or use something like /etc/aliases to redirect local delivery addresses to the gmail account you desire.

Without details its hard to be much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method would be to setup Simple SMTP (SSMTP). It can impersonate `sendmail` and relay mail to any other valid SMTP server including Gmail's servers.